# kubernetes expanding pvc for cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a pvc on my cluster.

I can expand it on my provider (digital ocean)

but then on the cluster do I need to somehow let it know that it expanded?

here is my file that I deployed to enable the creation of the pvc

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-pvc
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing volumes other than through the PVC object (e.g., the DigitalOcean cloud control panel) is not recommended as this can potentially cause conflicts. Additionally, **size updates will not be reflected in the PVC object status section immediately, and the section will eventually show the actual volume capacity**

The recommendation is to update the capacity through the PVC object using `kubectl edit` and the CSI Driver will update the volume by calling digital ocean API. From the [docs](https://github.com/digitalocean/csi-digitalocean#volume-expansion)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: csi-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  [...]
  resources:
    requests:
      # The field below can be increased.
      storage: 10Gi
      [...]
```

After successful expansion, the status section of the PVC object will reflect the actual volume capacity.

Comment: So would I just deploy the same file via: kubectl apply -f storage.yml?  I was under the impression if I used the same name it would say this pvc already exists. So if the size is larger it would know to increase the size? thanks

Comment: Use `kubectl edit` to edit the existing pvc object..it should automatically increase the volume size in digital ocean